# If I fix a basis, can I have different matrices representing the same linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

let $T(x,y)=(x+y,x-y)$.
Now if I fix my basis to be ${(1,-1),(0,1)}$, then we see that $T(1,-1)=(0,2)=0(1,-1)+2(0,1)$ and $T(0,1)=(1,-1)=(1,-1)+0(0,1)$. So we can say that the associated matrix is $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    2 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
but what stops me from expressing $ T(1,-1)=(0,2)=2(0,1)+0(1,-1)$ and $T(0,1)=(1,-1)=0(0,1)+(1,-1)$ leading to an associated matrix of $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix representing a linear transformation is unique for a given *ordered* basis. That is, changing the order of the basis elements may change the matrix representation, as you have shown.

A simpler thing to think about is that when the order of the basis elements changes, the vector representation for a given element of the vector space will change as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course the matrix representation, as for the vectors representation, depends upon the basis chosen. What is invariant is the rank and then the dimensions of $Im(T)$ and $Ker(T)$.